# PnP -- Add a claim value to a SP Group using PnP powershell

Tags: 2016, pnp-powershell

I was hoping to find an example where I could add a particular custom claim value to a SP group using PnP Powershell.

Basically do what is done below using PnP powershell

```
$ClaimValue = $_.ClaimValue
    if ($_.ClaimType -eq $ClaimTypeSchema.GroupSID)
    {
      $objUserAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($EnvUserDomain, $_.ClaimValue)
      $objUserSID = $null
      Write-Output ("Generating Security Identifier for account: '" + $_.ClaimValue + "' ...")
      $objUserSID = $objUserAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
      if ($objUserSID -eq $null)
      {
        continue
      }
      $ClaimValue = $objUserSID.Value
    }
    Write-Output ("   Adding Claim: '" + $_.ClaimType + "' with Value: '" + $ClaimValue + "' ...")
    $Claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -ClaimType $_.ClaimType -ClaimValue $ClaimValue -TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer $AuthenticationProvider
    $SPUserClaim = New-SPUser -UserAlias $Claim.ToEncodedString() -Web $RootWeb.Url
    $SecurityGroup.AddUser($SPUserClaim)
  }
  Write-Output "Completed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I can get away with hardcoding the expected formats using something like below

```
i:0ǵ.t|custom-adfs|First.Last
```

for more encodings refer to the article below

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx

Still I think it would be good to have a equivalent in PnP.

```
$Claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -ClaimType $_.ClaimType -ClaimValue $ClaimValue -TrustedIdentityTokenIssuer $AuthenticationProvider
$SPUserClaim = New-SPUser -UserAlias $Claim.ToEncodedString() -Web $RootWeb.Url
```